# Firebase - How to retrieve data from .once call

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-ios

so i am trying to retrieve data from the firebase with the following code"

```
loadblah(){
  var valueArray = [];
  valueArray = firebase.database().ref("/Users/johnny/files/").once('value', function(snapshot){
      console.log(snapshot.val()); //First output
      return snapshot.val();
  });

  console.log(valueArray); //Second output
}
```

Anyway, as you can see ive added some console.log's for debugging, and they get completely different results.

First Output is what i was hoping for, eg `{ fileOne: {title: blah, text: blah}, fileTwo... }` and so on. but for the second output, i get this.

[image]

Any idea how to go about retrieving data in `snapshot.val()`? Any help would be much appreciated, i am fairly new to this.

EDIT: Better yet if you could somehow show me how to use the .on feature for sync stuff that would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is pretty common for those working with Firebase for the first time.

The Firebase `once` call is an *asynchronous* operation and, as such, it will only be completed later on when your download is finally done — long *after* your `loadblah()` function returns. When it *does*, the provided function will be called and your data will be ready to use in`snapshot.val()`.

Conversely, the returned value, stored in your `valueArray` var, is a `firebase.Promise` which provides an alternative way to wait for such value to arrive.

You already provided a `function` for the `once` call, so you can ignore the promise route for now. In other words, add your snapshot processing logic *inside* the function passed to `once` (and ignore its return value).

Comment: Ohh i get it! So the functon(snapshot) is only being called after the items have downloaded. when i put the console.log() inside the function it works as expected. Quick question, how do i set a state within this function? it doesn't seem to let me - eg (this.setState is undefined)

Comment: @RyanTurnbull Weird... as [this guide shows](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html?m=1) it should be possible to call `this.setState` from there as well.

Comment: yeah it says this.setState is not a function, and is undefined

Comment: if your interested @PauloMattos i had to create a pointer to this, eg var that = this, and it worked as expected. weird.